# Django ChoiceField make only one choice readonly

Tags: python, django

I have a dropdown multichoice field in django, and I want to make only one value from the dropdown read only so it can't be edited, and leave the rest editable

I want if possible to do it in my view's get_form

here's what I'm doing so far :

```
form.fields["groups"].queryset = models.Group.objects.all()
form.fields["groups"].initial = models.Group.objects.filter(is_default=True)
```

So basicly I want the default value to always be selected ( selected and disabled )

[image]

Thanks for guiding me through this.

Comment: I don't think you can implement that in plain HTML, I would customize the UI behavior with some JS and add some form validation on Django side

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the field by setting the [**`disabled`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) to `True`:

```
form.fields['groups'].queryset = models.Group.objects.all()
form.fields['groups'].initial = models.Group.objects.filter(is_default=True)
form.fields['groups'].disabled = True
```

If you set this while constructing the form (in the `__init__` method), it will also prevent people from making "forged" POST requests with a different value. In other words: this does not only disables the field at the browsers client, but also prevents malicious requests.